# What is the javascript approach to an associative map with objects as keys (not strings but unique objects)?

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, dictionary, reference, associative-array

I'm looking for the javascript way to an associative map/array/hash that's using objects as keys. A replacement to what you can do in ActionScript 3 with the flash.utils.Dictionary. I'm sure java and C# have something like it too.

It'd work same as a normal generic Object based assoc[key] but instead of string-based properties you use whole objects as keys (it will match not on toString() like Object does but on unique instance). Very handy to decorate objects you don't own (by using the object as keys and your decorations as value).

Pseudo code:

```
decorations[objectA] = [lights, sparkles, ..];
decorations[objectB] = [skulls, spikes, ..];

if(someObject in decorations) 
    updateDecorations(someObject , decorations[someObject])
```

Illustration in javascript and why it's not working on Objects:

```
// make two objects with same toString() return value
var objA = {toString:function(){return 'foo'}};
var objB = {toString:function(){return 'foo'}};

//use objects as keys
var assoc = {};
assoc[objA] = 'dataA';
assoc[objB] = 'dataB';

// seperate instances are not equal
console.log(objA == objB);
// still same data associated: dataB, dataB
console.log(assoc[objA]);   
console.log(assoc[objB]);

//with a Dictionary instead of this would be dataA, dataB
```

Main point of issue is I need to match on object only (it's being used by some other process you're not to interfere with but we still need association). So no magic .__hash props or toString() overloading (if possible).

Any ideas?

edit: i checked around but it's all toString() or adding magic props

Comment: is there really not already some unique id field in the objects which you could use as the key?  if not, you'll need to add one -- or possibly use a serialization of the object contents as the key, though that sounds like a bad performance choice

Comment: i thought about that: i could take the property names, sort them and concat the values in that order and it'll give me a near unique key (assuming the data is different). but then i'd link the identity of the container to the data, seems unsafe.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a dictionary class in JS a while ago. It's definitely not ideal, since it uses an Array to store the values and keys, but works well for small collections.

You find it here:
https://github.com/creynders/creynders-js-lib

Answer (score 0):

I had done something similar where you associate an object (1 of 19 icons) onto a map. I pull the information from mysql through PHP and associate everything on a map with their X,Y coordinates.

When I add a mouse_rollover to all icons, I simply cycle through the array and find the X,Y coordinates match and display a panel with all the other values imported into the multidimensional arrays.

Do you see this helping? If so I can provide some of my code that I've used for doing this.
jc